# How to print sequence and ack number from TCP header

Tags: c, networking, tcp, network-programming

I'm working on a project and need to print out TCP sequence number and TCP ack number from the TCP header. Below is what I have done

```
ip = (struct iphdr*) buffer; //buffer is used to store the packet that I received
tcp = (struct tcphdr*) (buffer+(4*ip->ihl));

printf ("TCP sequence number = %d\n",ntohl(tcp->seq));
printf ("TCP ack number = %d\n",ntohl(tcp->ack_seq));
```

To ensure that I receive the packet correctly, I also print other information such as `ip->saddr`, `tcp->source` etc.. I have the same numbers as reported by Wireshark.

However, the numbers I printed out for sequence number and ack number are not matched. I got very big numbers (don't make any sense) for those two while Wireshark reports numbers that make sense such as Seq =1, Ack=1 or Seq=1, Ack=8, etc..

I noticed that next to sequence number and ack number reported in wireshark it says "relative sequence number" and "relative ack number" respectively. So I guess the numbers Wireshark reports are just relative numbers to something else, and the numbers that I print out from TCP header are the actual numbers.

Nevertheless, I want to print something as Wireshark reports, is it possible to do it? If so, please show me

Appreciate all the help, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wireshark sequence and ack numbers are relative to the first packets in the TCP connection (SYN from client to server, SYN and ACK from server to client).  So just record the actual sequence and ack numbers from those packets, and subtract those values from the actual values the packet you are printing.

For example, if the client sends its SYN with actual sequence number 100, then subtract 100 from the actual sequence values in the subsequent packets in that TCP connection.  This will give the relative sequence number.

Comment: Sorry @Craig for my late response. Just implemented your suggestion in my code and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help.